# What are the best practices for handling private keys on behalf of dApp users?

Tags: wallets, security, private-key

I have seen many answers and theory about it but didn't find any concrete example of how it should be done.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you're authoring a DApp, the best practice is to *not* handle anyone's private keys. Users of your app should use something like MetaMask.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's where I come from. Our users wouldn't be comfortable using something like MetaMask and what if they use Safari and not MetaMask supported browsers?

Comment: If they're not comfortable using MetaMask, what would they be comfortable with? Surely giving you their private key to a website would be worse from a security standpoint, but maybe there are other aspects of their concern?

Comment: Our users are non-techies. And we're very sure that they wont like it when we ask them to install MetaMask or anything else for that matter. I understand the security part but what are the alternatives, other than MetaMask of course.

Comment: The only other options are using web3 enabled browsers (eg Mist or Parity) which users are less likely to have than Chrome/Metamask or having them use a ledger/hardware wallet and using their respective packages and manually coding transaction signing.  That is if you want them signing / sending transactions.  For read only access to web3, you could provide your own web3 provider and not use Metamask’s web3.  That would allow them to *read* from the Blockchain.  But the short answer is, allowing users to send transactions without Metamask (eg Safari) is for right now not really easily doable

Comment: @carlolm typed pretty much what I was going to say. The only thing I'll add is that you *could* have them just paste in their private key, but if you allow users to do that, please strongly encourage them to put limited funds in a new account just for that purpose, since any security vulnerability in your app could result in them losing their entire balance.

Comment: Thanks @smarx and carlolm for your inputs. One last thing - to what extent MetaMask is used in production apps?

Comment: I don't think I've seen a production app that *doesn't* encourage the use of MetaMask. (Most should also work with Mist or Parity.)

Comment: Sorry to jump in there @smarx, agreed with your comments. I have a DApp and we use Metamask. A lot of ICOs over the past few months have used Metamask, so I would estimate that billions of dollars have flowed through Metamask. It’s the easiest way to get users to interact/authorize transactions with Smart Contracts. Cryptokitties used Metamask! The first Ethereum app that went viral.

Comment: Well, that gives me reason to seriously consider using MetaMask. Thanks again.